# Rectangle Arraylist Libgdx only the last work

Tags: java, libgdx

recently i'm making an game like doodle jump, but i'm having a problem :

I made a dynamic array for the platform where the players are going to fall

```
ArrayList<Rectangle> plRec = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
```

then i add 11 platform randomly in the array and then after the cicle other one , where the players will be create !

```
//in the create method
plTxt = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ghiaccio.png"));

recPartenza = new Rectangle(); //the rectangle where the player starts 
recPartenza.height = 25;
recPartenza.width = 100;
recPartenza.x = 50;
recPartenza.y = 10;

for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) { //11 rectangle added to the array
    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
    rec.height = 25;
    rec.width = 100;
    rec.x = MathUtils.random(50, 620);
    rec.y = MathUtils.random(50, 620);
    plRec.add(rec); //this add the rectangles randomlyzed to the array
}
plRec.add(recPartenza); // i add the start rectangle to the array
```

finally this will be rendered in the screen .
After i made a method that receive the position of the player and the position of the platforms
in the render method:

```
for (Rectangle rectangle: plRec) {
    if (IsOnTop(new Vector2(dpRec.x, dpRec.y), dpRec, new Vector2(rectangle.x, rectangle.y), rectangle)) {                                                                    
        //return true or false if the playes is on 3px up the platform
        gravity = 0;//player stops
    }
    else {
        gravity = 5; //plyer continue to fall
    }   
}
```

the player stops only up the last rectangle on the array ! Why this ? 
I want that the players stops up all the rectangles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake. You need to decide if *any of the rectangles matches a predicate*. In this case, the predicate is "player stands on this rectangle".

You can change that to:

```
boolean playerStands = false; //if player stands on any platform
for (Rectangle rectangle : plRec) {
    if (/*same condition*/) {
        playerStands = true;
        break; //no need to check the other ones
    } //no else
}
gravity = playerStands ? 0 : 5;
```

Comment: In your case, every `Rectangle` rewrote the `gravity` variable, so every rectangle except for the last one had no effect on the result, because the last rectangle always set the `gravity` variable regardless on any previous assignments.